# Plot tree graph from Pandas dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, graph, tree

I am trying to plot a tree from a Pandas dataframe but I don't know which is the correct data structure I must use and how can I solve it.

The dataset has 4 columns: source, destination, application and timemark.

For example,  a row in the dataset could be:

```
192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.200 | ping | 10:00AM
```

I would like to plot a tree graph generating a node for each of the sources, and showing the adjacency of each source with the destinations who has communicated with, and an adjacency of each destination with all the applications that this destination has used with the source and finally showing the adjacency of each (source, destination, application) leaf, with all the timemarks of the sessions that used this application between this destination and this source.

Could you please tell me how can I find a Python solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/):

"NetworkX is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks."

You can feed your dataset to populate a graph and then plot the graph.

For example:

```html
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node('192.168.1.1')
G.add_node('192.168.1.100')
G.add_node('192.168.1.200')
G.add_edge('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.100', object='10')
G.add_edge('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.200', object='11')

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = nx.shell_layout(G))
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos = nx.shell_layout(G))
plt.show()
```

would give you:
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate how you would feed a whole dataset and not entering every value manually?